# Link Azure Connection String with Django WebApp?

Tags: python, django, azure, environment-variables

It's my first website on Azure with Python. I developed before with .NET. Sorry if my question is a basic one.

I deployed my Django website on Azure. It works fine with the DB settings in the settings.py.

Next step, I thought, is to transfer the DB settings to Azure's Application Settings - Connection Strings, what I did.

I am aware that I need the prefix MYSQLCONNSTR_connectionString1.

How can I now link my Django/Python WebApp with the Connection String in the Azure Application Settings?

I would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't connect the database via Environment Variables in Azure's Application settings - Connection Strings, though I tried various approaches. Still would be grateful for help how it can be done.

What worked instead, reading https://godjango.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-python/:

Enter in Azure Application settings - App settings the single DB connection values:

```
KEY                  VALUE
DATABASE_NAME:       <database>
DATABASE_USER:       <dbuser>
DATABASE_PASSWORD:   <dbpassword>
DATABASE_HOST:       <host>
DATABASE_PORT:       <port>
```

And in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME', ''),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER', ''),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD', ''),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST', ''),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT', ''),    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `import os` to import `os` package in your Django code like `settings.py`, then get these environment variables which be defined in `App settings` or `Connection strings` of the tab `Application settings` on Azure portal via the code `os.getenv("<environ-var-name>")`.

For the environment variable defined in `App settings`, you just pass the variable name defined like `VARNAME` as the argument for `os.getenv()`.

To get the value of the environment variable defined in `Connection strings`, you need to add the different prefix or surfix for the variable name like `VARNAME`, as below.

1. For `SQL Database`, using prefix `SQLAZURECONNSTR` with infix symbol `_` for `VARNAME` is `SQLAZURECONNSTR_VARNAME`.
2. For `SQL Server`, using prefix `SQLCONNSTR` with infix symbol `_` for `VARNAME` is `SQLCONNSTR_VARNAME`.
3. For `MySQL`, using prefix `MYSQLCONNSTR` with infix symbol `_` for `VARNAME` is `MYSQLCONNSTR_VARNAME`.
4. For `Custom`, using surfix `MYSQLCONNSTR` with infix symbol `_` for `VARNAME` is `VARNAME_CONNECTSTRING`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I add just os.getenv("MYSQLCONNSTR_cexymysql") to the settings DB

Comment: What you say is right, but explains just half the way. I still don't know how to add os.getenv("MYSQLCONNSTR_cexymysql") to settings.py that it is accepted by Azure. If I add plain os.getenv("MYSQLCONNSTR_cexymysql") in the settings.py on Azure I get a "ImproperlyConfigured" error, if I add DATABASES = {
    'default': os.getenv("MYSQLCONNSTR_cexymysql")
} it's "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." Thanks again, if you could take me on from here?

Comment: Thread is quite old but for the cases like me who ended up in figuring this out. At this time (2020-04-02), in order to access the connecting string that is stored in the Web App settings, you need to use `CUSTOMCONNSTR_VARNAME` as environment variable name instead.